# How to preset service instances with systemd

Tags: systemd

I am packaging an instanced service@ as an RPM. The package should automatically enable the preset instances that the local admin has already prescribed with a .preset file. What is the "systemctl preset {what goes here}" command line to enable them automatically when the RPM is installed?

Sample /etc/systemd/system-preset/20-mypolicy.preset:

```
enable myservice@.service one three nine
```

The list of instances is not known at RPM creation time, and it would be different on every system that `myservice` gets installed to, subject to the local admin discretion and needs.

The local admin could do `systemctl enable myservice@{one,two,nine}` after `rpm install ...`, but this seems to defeat the purpose of presets.

I also suspect I misunderstood how service instance presets should be specified based on [systemd.unit Example 2](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.preset.html). On my CentOS7 system with `systemd-219-78.el7.x86_64`, running `systemctl preset-all` disables the three instances listed in the preset file, which is **unexpected**.

Is it possible that systemd 219 does not in fact support instance presets, even though it appears to support instances, as well as presets?

This particular version is the latest available at the moment on CentOS 7, which is the system I need to deploy to.

Comment: `{what goes here}` -> `myservice@.service`? (NOT TESTED)

Comment: Your distro might be shipping a `disable *` preset, although I'm not sure if you actually need to override it (I mean like with under /etc/... with the same name)

Comment: The "myservice@.service" syntax yields "missing the instance name", and exit code 1; `preset myservice@*.service` succeeds with exit code 0, without enabling the services.  `preset myservice@one.service` does succeeds with exit code 0 and enables. CentOS7 ships with the `disable *` preset in /usr/lib/systemd/system-preset/99-default-disable.preset, and my reading of the manual also says I don't need to overwrite it locally; my 20-mypolicy.preset should override it because it is lexically before 99-default-disable.preset; The overriding logic seems to work as expected for non-instanced services

Comment: Likely in the version you use it is more or less bugged. I just tested on 254.1 and `preset meh@.service` works as expected. I even get an error for `meh@*.service` (something like "globs are not supported" and "invalid unit name after escaping * to \x2a")

Comment: `Is it possible that systemd 219 does not in fact support instance presets, even though it appears to support instances, as well as presets?` As mentioned by "Tom Yan" in the comments of the OP, it is most likely a bug in the quite old version 219 of systemd you use. Further more i suppose you do a `systemctl daemon-reload` between installing your template in the system and BEFORE you do the `systemctl preset` sequence right?

Comment: Thank you @TomYan, @TrippleMoon... the system is CentOS7, and 219 is the latest available through the official channels. I have done the testing by manually running `systemctl daemon-reload` and `systemctl preset myservice@.service`, to remove the RPM scriptlet as a variable. I'm not able to get the instances enabled unless I use the `systemctl preset myservice@**instance-name**.service`, which defeats the purpose of templates. Since the manpage for `systemd.preset` makes no mention of instanced services, I must accept the answer that 219 does not support instance presets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on empirical evidence in the comments (thanks @TomYan), later systemd versions, like 254.1 do work as I expected.

Also the [systemd.preset manpage for 219](https://web.archive.org/web/20150418234030/https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.preset.html) that comes with my systemd does not mention template instances at all, while the [most current version](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.preset.html) does, which means the feature was likely added sometime after version 219.

The conclusion, and the answer is that **systemd 219 does not support service instance presets**.